# Running pulseaudio in Windows 10 to get audio output in Windows subsystem for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: audio, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pulse-audio

I have installed Ubuntu for Windows subsystem for linux. I would like to get some audio to work in Ubuntu. I have read the following tutorials:

https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2017/11/setting-up-wsl-with-graphics-and-audio.html
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Enabling_Sound
https://x410.dev/cookbook/wsl/enabling-sound-in-wsl-ubuntu-let-it-sing/

They all say basically the same thing, install pulseaudio-1.1 in windows, install a modified version of pulseaudio in ubuntu, then any audio file played in ubuntu will direct it's output to the windows pulseaudio running in the background which will send the audio to the hardware

Pulseaudio for windows is not working for me. Here the error I am getting:

```
PS E:\data_aba\Work\linux_dream\ORIGINAL\MYDOWNLOADS\pulseaudio-1.1\bin> .\pulseaudio.exe
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core.c: failed to allocate shared memory pool. Falling back to a normal memory pool.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
E: [(null)] modules/module-waveout.c: failed to parse module arguments.
E: [(null)] pulsecore/module.c: Failed to load module "module-waveout" (argument: "sink_name=output source_name=input record = 0"): initialization failed.
E: [(null)] daemon/main.c: Failed to load directory.
E: [(null)] daemon/main.c: Module load failed.
E: [(null)] daemon/main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
```

I have tried running this in both cmd and powershell and I get the same error. What can be done to fix this?

Windows version:

Windows 10 Home 64 bit version 1909 OS build: 18363.778

Answer (score 2):

As a further comment to the above answer, I'd like to add that nssm ( https://nssm.cc/ ) is a proper app-as-a-service manager for modern Windows "Services" integration which I have successfully used to run Pulse (and other items) on-boot/login/etc to serve audio for both WSL and actual Linuxen for a multi-platform single-endpoint audio solution.

(I'd love to post this as a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have the reputation.)

Answer (score 1):

`E: [(null)] pulsecore/module.c: Failed to load module "module-waveout" (argument: "sink_name=output source_name=input record = 0"): initialization failed.`

There shouldn't be any spaces around the equal sign. Change "record = 0" to "record=0"

Comment: please be more specific, how? thanks